# How can i use :not to give some specific CSS to parent element not to the child and sub-child?

Tags: html, css

Hello this is the code

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
<span>Lorem</span>
<span>
  <strong style="font-size: 18px">
    sometext
    <span style="font-size: 12px">
      <em>ipsum</em>
    </span>
  </strong>
</span>
<span style="font-size: 14px">dolar sit amet</span>

<span class="input__math">
  <span class="katex">
    <span class="katex-mathml">
        <span style="font-size: 14px">
          <strong>x</strong>
          <sup style="font-size: 10px">2</sup>
        </span>
        +
        <span style="font-size: 14px">
          <strong>y</strong>
          <sup style="font-size: 10px">2</sup>
        </span>
        =
        <span>
          <span style="font-size: 16px">
            <strong>
              1
            </strong>
          </span>
        </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>

</div>
```

and i am trying to add some CSS like `font-size: 20px !important;` inside all the content of **content-wrapper** class except math-content like whatever is coming inside the **input__math** class sholud not change. i tried like this

```css
.content-wrapper *:not(.input__math *) {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

But it's not working, Please help if you have any solution

here i have created a fiddle with some demo content with inline-css, please check

https://jsfiddle.net/u5xb49Lr/4/

Comment: `.content-wrapper :not(.input__math)`?

Comment: You can't have a child combinator inside a `:not` statement.

Comment: @morpheus if will use without * then CSS will not apply to all child elements, because somewhere in child elements inline-css is coming which should override.

Comment: here i have created a fiddle with some demo content with inline-css, 

please check      
https://jsfiddle.net/u5xb49Lr/4/

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you do not want the font-size of .input__math **or the font-size of all .input__math's child elements** to change.

Using :not(.input__math) won't work here, since this will not target child elements of .input__math (because these, although they are children of 'input__math', don't have the class 'input__math' themselves).

Here's a different solution. CSS you apply to child elements will override CSS applied to parent elements. Therefore, you could do this:

```
.content-wrapper {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

And then this:

```
.input__math {
  font-size: <other font size>;
}
```

Comment: I can't give any font-size to `input__math` class because it's math content so there different font-sizes may come as inline-css, which i don't want to override.

Comment: As long as you don't add '!important' (which is bad practice anyway) to any of the font-size values, inline styles will override styles from external or internal stylesheets. So you'll be fine! Google 'css cascading order' to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS style:

```
.content-wrapper:not(.input__math) {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

That should do the job. There's no need for * sign in there.

Comment: This would just look at `.content-wrapper` elements which don't have `.input__math` class